# Can a werewolf join the Dawnguard?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

It seems that you can't join the Dawnguard as a werewolf. They tried to mow me down the moment I entered the zone, and got a farmer killed (my companion) before I could leave the zone.

Can you join the Dawngard then reacquire werewolf status without the Dawngard trying to mount your pelt on their wall?

Comment: WHat about not going in in werewolf form? *everyone* hates you in werewolf form.

Comment: Are you just a werewolf or are you in werewolf form? The dawnguard should not kill you if you are just a werewolf (or a well fed vampire for that matter).

You could also have pissed off the dawnguard in a different way. Did you kill a member of the dawnguard faction?

Answer (score 3):

Just like Arperum said in the comment section, you can't do much in werewolf form. Especially go into a town or try to join the Dawnguard. Reload a previous save file, don't be a werewolf and join the Dawnguard.

If you are given a mission to kill someone, you can do THAT in werewolf form, but no interaction with NPC's will go successfully.